# How to take the average of every nth elements in c++

Tags: c++, vector

I am programming for fun and I wanted to take the averages of every nth elements. For instance, I have 1,000 elements in the vector and I want to take the average of every 100 elements, how do I do that using c++.

I tried using modulo, but my logic isn't right.

```
    float av;
    vector<float> average;
    vector<int> vec = {1, 3, 5, 5, 6, 2, 12, 54};

    for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {

        if(i % 2 == 0) {
            av += vec[i];
            average.push_back(av);
        }

        cout << average << endl;
    }
```

I keep getting something different. For instance, for the first average I get 1;

Comment: If you struggle with an algorithm then try to write it on a paper with a pen and not in C++. Try to step through it by hand and when you get it working then write it using the code. Why did you use modulo? Where do you the averaging in the code you posted? Why is `average` a vector, shouldn't it be a number?

Comment: The question will be more clear if you add the expected result with your vector. Should be 16 (average of 3, 5, 2, 54) or the vector {2, 5, 4, 33}? (the average each pair of element)?

Answer (score 1):

Great question.  Here is a simple solution that I came up with.  I use `periodicity` to represent the steps between vector elements that you want to use.  Then, as the number of elements may not be an integral multiple of the periodicity, I use the ceiling function to grab one more element for the division.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
  int total = 0;
  uint count;
  float average;
  const uint periodicity = 2;
  std::vector<int> vec {1, 3, 5, 5, 6, 2, 12, 54, 18};

  for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i = i + periodicity) {
    total += vec[i];

  }

  count = ceil((double) vec.size()/periodicity);
  average = (double) total / count;
  std::cout << "sum: " << total << ", count: " << count
  << ", average: " << average << std::endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you could change `i++` to `i += 100` and then keep a running sum of every element you have encountered as well as a count of the number of elements you have summed and then return the sum divided by the count to get the average.

Answer (score 0):

Average is **(sum / number_of_elements)**: `(vec[0] + vec[1] + ... + vec[N - 1]) / N`

Only division occurs at the Nth element, sum is for every number:

```
int N = 2;
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
{
  av += vec[i];

  if (i % N == 0)
  {        
    average.push_back(av / N);
    av = 0; // reset sum for next average
  }
}
```